# Google Compute Engine: How to prevent the hostname redirects to IP

Tags: hosting, google-compute-engine, web-hosting

I created a Google Compute Engine Project. 
Following the steps at 
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns
I was able to put my domain name in the browser URL and direct me to my project index page. However, when I click on the page, all redirected page in the address bar shows the IP instead of my domain name. 
Is there any other configurations that I needed to set up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, this is a wordpress configuration, 
It needs to set the site address as the new URL